# Xamarin - Panning and scaling the view of a graph

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to make a 2d coordinate graph where you can put coordinates on it. The graph can be zoomed in and out, and panned in all directions. I'm thinking of making the screen kind of like a camera, looking down on the graph. Simply moving the camera lets you see different parts of the graph. Is that possible to do? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Look at SkiaSharp

Comment: of course its possible to do this, but it just might mean you will need to do a lot of work